# Can I use @EnvironmentObject in SwiftUI for all shared data?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-environment

There are `@State`, `@ObservedObject` and `@EnvironmentObject` bindings in `SwfitUI` to share data between views and other objects. Each has its designated usage but `@EnvironmentObject` seems to be the most powerful and easiest to use. So, can I use it for all state variables and shared data? Are there any downsides to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `@EnvironmentObject` is for classes. So if you want to bind primitive type like Int - you can only use `Binding`.
Second, I think it will couse a problems when you try to define more then one `@EnvironmentObject` of same type. So, when you can use `Binding` - you should do that. Thats only my appinion.

```
class SomeClass: ObservableObject{
    @Published var value: Int
    init(value: Int){
        self.value = value
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var one: SomeClass = SomeClass(value: 1)
    @State var two: SomeClass = SomeClass(value: 2)
    var body: some View {
        Adss().environmentObject(one).environmentObject(two)
    }
}
struct Adss: View{
    @EnvironmentObject var two: SomeClass
    var body: some View{
        Text("there must be two: \(two.value)")//prints "1"
    }
}
```

you will have to define all the objects of needed type in straight order even if you don't need them